# How to get attribute value from xml?

Tags: php, xml

I saw lot of examples but nothing is working perfectly. This is the array i got after parsing.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
    (
        [areaUnits] => acre
    )

)
```

Now i try to get attributes,like this:

```
var_dump($list->attributes());
```

I got this error:

```
 var_dump(): Node no longer exists
```

Comment: please provide the xml file so we can have a better view of you issue

Comment: It's a huge file. I just gave you some node here.
define("XMLNS_COMMON","http://rets.org/xsd/RETSCommons");

<Listing>
<LivingArea>2200</LivingArea>
  <LotSize commons:areaUnits="acre">0.897</LotSize>
  <YearBuilt>1992</YearBuilt>
</Listing>

Now i get the array for this
$list = $eachListing->LotSize->children(XMLNS_COMMON);

Comment: based on what you provided, there is no way to replicate your issue. For me at least, I need: more php code before and after the var_dump, at least 1 xml node

Comment: @-Ares 
<Listings xmlns="http://rets.org/xsd/Syndication/2012-03" xmlns:commons="http://rets.org/xsd/RETSCommons"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xml:lang="en-us">
 <Listing>
<LivingArea>2200</LivingArea>
  <LotSize commons:areaUnits="acre">0.897</LotSize>
  <YearBuilt>1992</YearBuilt>
  <ListingDate>2012-01-06</ListingDate>
  <ListingTitle>Ranch, Ranch - Morgantown, WV</ListingTitle>
  <FullBathrooms>2</FullBathrooms>
</Listing>
</Listings>

$xml=simplexml_load_file($filename); is this ok now for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function xml_attribute($object, $attribute)
{
    if(isset($object[$attribute]))
    return (string) $object[$attribute];
}
print xml_attribute($xml, 'areaUnits'); //prints "acre"
?>
```

Comment: I tried this 
print $this->xml_attribute($list, 'areaUnits');
but it's not satisfy this "isset($object[$attribute]". I am using Yii is this any problem for Yii

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/50504-how-to-display-the-data-extracted-from-xml-to-be-displayed-in-yii-cgridview/ will this satisfy your question? i'm not sure the above code for yii

Comment: Your code should work perfectly. But i don't know why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Obtaining the attributes of a `SimpleXMLElement` is very straight forward.

#### The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <node attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2">data</node>
</root>
```

#### The PHP:

```
// assume $xml variable contains the XML document above
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml)
$value1 = $sxe->node->attributes()->attribute1;
$value2 = $sxe->node->attributes()->attribute2;
```

In your example above, `$list` MUST reference an actual XML node in order for you to attempt to access its attributes. Based on your error, it sounds like you're not doing that, which can often happen if you modify the XML structure referenced by `$list` at run time.